# PHP - Remove associative array element and assign it to a variable in one action?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out if there's a way of removing an array element and at the same time storing that value in a variable.

i.e.

```
$array = [
    'foo' => 'a',
    'bar' => 'b'
];

// Perform the following with one action?
$var = $array['foo'];
unset($array['foo']);
```

Edit: I mean if it can be done without a custom function.

Comment: You can always write your own function to do it: `function array_remove(&$arr,$key) { $val = $arr[$key]; unset($arr[$key]); return $val; }`

Comment: If it's the first or last, array_shift() or array_pop(). But I don't think you can do it to the middle without your own wrapper function.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Of course, but it's not worth it.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. You could make an own function, but the overhead from the function call will result in a worse perfomance, because there the code above has to be executed anyway. Why do you need to make it in one operation or is it just out of curiosity?

Comment: @JRsz Just curiosity, to see if my code can be further optimised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is but it's slow and ugly.

```
$var = array_splice($array, array_search('foo', array_keys($array)), 1)['foo'];
```

I'd stick with the 2-liner.

Comment: well, this is not one function to do it only a construct out of many functions build into one expression. And I agree with your final comment :D

Comment: Yeah, there is not a single operation for this in PHP. Assignment + `unset()` is as simple (and fast) as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done under certain circumstances.

There are two functions which do what sort of what you want.

```
array_pop($stack);
array_shift($stack);
```

But array_pop gets and removes only the last element and array_push the first of the array which can lead to unexxpected behaviour of your code if you are using an associative array.

However if you can restructure your array to fit for these functions without increasing the complexity (which would make this whole thing pointless) it can be done.

The two links for the functions are:

[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-pop.php)

[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-shift.php)

An entire reference of the array function can be found here. Maybe you find something that serves you the way you need it to:
[Array functions reference](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.array.php)